# How to compile intersecting enum and struct in two different files?

Tags: struct, compiler-errors, mql4, mql5

I've these two simple files:

#### `Trade.mqh`

```
class Trade;
class Trade {
  public:
    #include "Order.mqh"
    struct TradeRequest {
      ENUM_ORDER_STATE type;
    };
};
```

#### `Order.mqh`

```
class Order;
class Trade;
#include "Trade.mqh"

class Order : public Trade {
  public:
    enum ENUM_ORDER_STATE {
      ORDER_FOO,
      ORDER_BAR
    };
    TradeRequest order;
};
```

However the compilation fails.

How do I fix the compilation problem without keeping the same files and not moving the structure to one file?

---

I want to keep the structure how it is (two separate files), trade related struct in Trade class file which has dependency to order related enum which is defined in Order class file.

The errors are:

- MQL4/MQL5 for `Trade.mqh`

  > 'Trade' struct undefined (Order.mqh)
  >
  > 'TradeRequest' - declaration without type (Order.mqh)
- MQL4 for `Order.mqh`

  > 'ENUM_ORDER_STATE' - declaration without type (Trade.mqh)
  >
  > 'Trade' - struct undefined (Order.mqh)
  >
  > ';' - unexpected end of program (Order.mqh)

  In MQL5 compiles, but with the warning that enumeration already defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare `enum` above `class Trade`, I do not think there's any reason to assign `enum` as property of the class.

Comment: I don't think this will work, as far as remember, it wasn't working either. Did it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Support Team from MQL5 confirmed that it is impossible to compile this code if ENUM_ORDER_STATE is declared inside of the Order class.

The only workaround is to define dependee elements (enum) above the definition of struct.